# Clear Variable Cache?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, caching

I have a simple calendar that when you click on a day a window pops up allowing you to then click on a meal to apply to the day. My problem is that if you click on a day to bring up the pop up and then you click close without selecting a meal, when you then go to select another day and a meal it will add the meal to the previous day you clicked as well as the one you wanted.

Is there a way to clear variables so that this doesn't happen? I'm still relatively new to jQuery so any assistance would really help.

The code I have is as follows:

```
$('#meal-planner .add-meal').click(function(event) {

        var theMenu = '#the-menu';
        var dayType = $(this);
        var dayTypeClone = $(this).clone();
        var mealType = $(this).data("mealtype");

        // Show The Targeted Menu
        $(theMenu + '> section').removeClass('active');
        $("#" + mealType).addClass('active');
        $(theMenu).addClass('active');

        // Clone and Append
        $('#the-menu .jsMealItem').click(function(e) {
            var mealClone = $(this).find('figure').clone();
            dayType.replaceWith(mealClone);
            $(theMenu).removeClass('active');
        });

        // Close Menu
        $('button#close').click(function(event) {
            $(theMenu).removeClass('active');
        });

    });
```

Comment: Why are you binding click handler inside event handler? Might be you need `.off()` like `$('#the-menu .jsMealItem').off('click').click(function(e) {`

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly.

Comment: Glad I can help :)